# Transfering code between Arduinos

Tags: arduino

Me and a some other students have this idea that we want to put to reality. Our idea is to be able to make it possible for one Arduino to change the program of another Arduino.

This to be able to create sort of "Creatures" that could infect each others with infections.

Basically want we want to create can best be described as :

```
"Infected"                          "Healthy"
<code>                               <code>
<infected>                           <healthy>
</code>                              </code>
```

"Infected"--->"Healthy"

```
<code> 
<healthy> 
<infected* (or infection)> 
</code>
```

Do you guys think this is possible with Arduino or do you think we should use a different platform for this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't say anything about how these Arduinos are going to communicate but let's assume [Bluetooth Low Energy](https://learn.adafruit.com/introduction-to-bluetooth-low-energy/introduction) (BLE). Let's also assume you establish a messaging protocol which includes how and when the devices communicate, and the format the communications takes (perhaps one of the [JSON variants for Arduino](https://github.com/bblanchon/ArduinoJson) or [MTQQ](http://mqtt.org/) wiith an [Arduino MTQQ lib](http://knolleary.net/arduino-client-for-mqtt/) if you are connecting over Wifi/Ethernet).

Then yes, given the above, you could do what you describe. And you would not be transferring "code" per se between clients but rather data (health points, hits, etc). If you are thinking you can reprogram one Arduino from another, then that is a wholly different question.

Comment: I am indeed thinking about reprogramming one arduino from another, so really adding comepletely new code to an arduino from another. But they way they communicate is still open for debate, that has not been decided yet.